# Wireless CCTV Network reactivation question Entertained?

Tags: discussion

Are CCTV network questions entertained?

Comment: Could you expand on this a bit? Although mediums can be the same in certain cases, traditional CCTV really isn't a network and typically signal is generated in one direction.

Comment: Ok I will, it's a wireless CCTV Network,  deployed in an outdoor environment, I need to know what is causing the entire network is offline.

Comment: Possible causes: Power, Core Camera is offline affecting the edge cameras.

Comment: We would need a lot more information to help:  a diagram, description of equipment, configuration files, just to name a few.

Comment: Yeah, i'll get the diagram posted in a bit, just doing some edits.